# Pressing urge to move from Thunderbird 2 to 3?

Tags: thunderbird

I'm still running Thunderbird 2 as 3 was screwy for a while. Anyone made the switch recently who can tell me if or why 3 is preferred now?

Comment: I've been holding off since I didn't like the fact that the search worked across all email accounts not just one account.

Comment: I switched some time ago. It's stable, but I don't use half the features so I can't really post an answer saying "go for it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the search feature better than in TB2. In-body search got better as well.

Mail handling is almost the same (as TB2), with all the bugfixes recently, it now works flawlessly.
If you prefer, TB3 can integrate with Win7 search, so you can search mails from the start menu.